# How to create scatterplot using data subset's x,y coordinates and assign color based on larger dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to plot an outcome measure (here, dendritic spine density) by x,y sampling coordinates. I've assigned points their color by density value. I'd now like to plot subsets of my data (aka instead of all data, restrict to experimental groups e.g. "juvenile males") but generate point colors from the overall spine density distribution.

I'm not super familiar with ggplot yet, so first thing I tried was

```
plot1 <- ggplot(juvmales, aes(x=ML, y=DV, color=spines$Density)) + 
           geom_point(size=3.5) + 
           expand_limits(y=-1850)


### color plot of density by coordinates ALL DATA
plot1 <- ggplot(spines, aes(x=ML, y=DV, color=Density)) + 
           geom_point(size=3.5) + 
           expand_limits(y=-1850)
plot1 + scale_color_gradient(low="blue",high="red", space="Lab")

### color plot of density by coordinates juvenile males
plot2 <- ggplot(juvmales, aes(x=ML, y=DV, color=Density)) + 
           geom_point(size=3.5) + 
           expand_limits(y=-1850)
plot2 + scale_color_gradient(low="blue",high="red", space="Lab")
```

Comment: Did your question cut off? What was the problem with your trial? Please post the `dput` of *spines* and *juvmales* datasets and show their assignments if one is a subset of the other.

Comment: get the range of overall data and assign it to a variable `spine_ovrall_rnge <-sort(c(0,range(spines$Density))` and then use this for assigning colors
`+scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(-3,3),
  colours=c("blue", "darkmagenta", "red"),
  breaks=spine_ovrall_rnge, labels=format(spine_ovrall_rnge))`.

Answer (score 0):

get the range of overall data and assign it to a variable

```
spine_ovrall_rnge <- range(spines$Density) 
# and then add a zero for midpoint
spine_ovrall_rnge0 <-sort(c(0,spine_ovrall_rnge)# for assigning colors
 #Use below to add to plot2 call
+scale_fill_gradientn(limits = spine_ovrall_rnge,
      colours=c("blue", "darkmagenta", "red"),
      breaks=spine_ovrall_rnge0, labels=format(spine_ovrall_rnge0))
```